# select into for of cursor doesnt recognize my atribute

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

i want to get the constraint of table but i can't do that, the value is not correct.
I can't use meta.data_base because it's for a academic study project so.. how can i solve it ?

if i do :

```
create table EMPRESTIMO(
cod_emprestimo number constraint pk_tab_emprestimo primary key,
data_emprestimo date ,
cod_usuario number(3) constraint id_usuario references USUARIO(cod_usuario)
);



create or replace function built_ddl_table(name_t varchar2)
return varchar2
is
cursor table_object is select column_name,data_type,data_length,data_precision,data_scale from user_tab_cols where lower(table_name) = lower(name_t);
resultado varchar2(255) := '';
const_name varchar2(255) := '';
begin
    resultado := 'CREATE TABLE ' || name_t || '(';

    for x in table_object loop
        select constraint_name into const_name from user_cons_columns where lower(table_name) = lower(name_t) and lower(column_name) = lower('COD_EMPRESTIMO');
        resultado := resultado || const_name;
    end loop;
    resultado := resultado || ');';
    return resultado;
end;
/

clear screen;
select built_ddl_table('EMPRESTIMO')as DLL from dual;
```

[result code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY5xN.png)
,but if i do ::

```
create table EMPRESTIMO(
cod_emprestimo number constraint pk_tab_emprestimo primary key,
data_emprestimo date ,
cod_usuario number(3) constraint id_usuario references USUARIO(cod_usuario)
);



create or replace function built_ddl_table(name_t varchar2)
return varchar2
is
cursor table_object is select column_name,data_type,data_length,data_precision,data_scale from user_tab_cols where lower(table_name) = lower(name_t);
resultado varchar2(255) := '';
const_name varchar2(255) := '';
begin
    resultado := 'CREATE TABLE ' || name_t || '(';

    for x in table_object loop
        select constraint_name into const_name from user_cons_columns where lower(table_name) = lower(name_t) and lower(column_name) = lower(x.column_name);
        resultado := resultado || const_name;
    end loop;
    resultado := resultado || ');';
    return resultado;
end;
/

clear screen;
select built_ddl_table('EMPRESTIMO')as DLL from dual;
```

[result of code 2 :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chlyB.png)

I dont know whats happening , can someone explain it for me ?

Comment: It would be easier if you have cut'n'pasted the output from a SQL session rather than posting screenshots. Many of us can't access image dumps (because of firewall rules) or choose not to (because of previous bad experiences).

Comment: Why not join the tables?

Comment: Beyond that, why are you re-inventing the functionality of Oracle's [DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885)?

Comment: i cant use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL() , because it's for a academic study project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data for `DATA_EMPRESTIMO` in `user_cons_columns` so concatenation fails here. For this specific example You could use `select max(constraint_name)`. But `listagg` is simpler:

```
create or replace function built_ddl_table(name_t varchar2) return varchar2 is
    resultado varchar2(255) := '';
begin
    select listagg(constraint_name, ' ') within group (order by column_name)
      into resultado
      from user_cons_columns 
      where lower(table_name) = lower('EMPRESTIMO');

    resultado := 'CREATE TABLE ' || name_t || '(' || resultado || ');';
    return resultado;
end;
```

Comment: Great, vote up, here is DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68c55e51a0a970d72fc1666e68c4f3b6 where Ihave removed one more line :)

Comment: The stretch was not exactly what I needed but the explanation helped a lot !! Thank you !!